# Release MKMapView after Center on user location

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

The code below works great but once you try to scroll around on the map or anywhere away from the user location, it pulls it right back and centers back on the user location. It won't release it.

How would you let it release after it centers in on the user's location after it loads?

```
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class MapView : UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()) {
            locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    let location = locations.last as CLLocation
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
    self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: I am have same issue were you able to figure it out?

Comment: No sir user2562080 I have not yet. Hopefully someone will chime in. Until then I will research the MKMapView files for more information.